# css/xpath selector to exclude the child node in the element when using selenium webdriver (java)

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

CSS/xpath selector to get the link text excluding the text in `.muted`.

I have html like this:

```
<a href="link">
          Text
   <span class="muted"> –text</span>
</a>
```

When I do `getText()`, I get the complete text like, `Text-text`. Is it possible to exclude the muted subclass text ?

Tried `cssSelector = "a:not([span='muted'])"` doesn't work.

`xpath = "//a/node()[not(name()='span')][1]"`

> ERROR: The result of the xpath expression `"//a/node()[not(name()='span')][1]"` is: [objectText]. It should be an element.

Comment: `cssSelector = "a span:not(.muted)` should work

Comment: Thanks @winner_joiner. But this doesn't work. It returns an empty set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK this cannot be done with `CSS` selector only. You can try to use `JavaScriptExecutor` to get required text.

As you didn't mention programming language you use I show you example on `Python`:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href="link"]')
driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue', link)
```

This will return just `"Text"` without `" -text"`

Comment: Thank you. This works but was looking if there is some other way as well. Probably using xpath selector or jquery ?

Comment: `XPath` to get required text is `normalize-space(//a[@href="link"]/text())`, but `selenium` doesn't support this syntax...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using Selenium WebDriver's API. You have to handle it in your code as follows:

```
// Get the entire link text
String linkText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='link']")).getText();

// Get the span text only
String spanText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='link']/span[@class='muted']")).getText();

// Replace the span text from link text and trim any whitespace
linkText.replace(spanText, "").trim();
```

Comment: Thanks. That helps.