# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //pre/*[not(self::b)]

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

https://www.codechef.com/ACMIND17/problems/STDDEV/
I am trying to get the Input and Output of the following question using python script but getting the following error

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //pre/*[not(self::b)]

You can easily find that both pre and b are present in source code and b is child of pre than why this error I am just trying to exclude b tags

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.codechef.com/ACMIND17/problems/STDDEV/')
str=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//pre/*[not(self::b)]").text;
print(str);
```

I just started learning all this today so sorry if it is something stupid

Comment: possible duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918983/css-xpath-selector-to-exclude-the-child-node-in-the-element-when-using-selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately selenium find_element method expect an element as return value so we can't use `//pre/text()[1]` for input or `//pre/text()[2]` for output. So we have to relay on the javascript to get the desired output.

Simple approach is to use the method that will extract the text from the given position in the element. You can use this method across your application so would prefer this method approach.

Note: The `textPosition` in the method is nothing but the text node index. For example in this case input value is the first textnode, output value is the second textnode.

```
def get_text_from_parent_by_postion(element, textPosition=1):
    return driver.execute_script(
        """ var parent = arguments[0];
            var textPosition = arguments[1];
            var txtPosition = 0;
            var child = parent.firstChild;
            var textValue="";
            while(child) {
              if (child.nodeType === 3){                        
                if (txtPosition===textPosition){
                  textValue = child.textContent;                
                  break;
                }}else{txtPosition+=1;}
              child = child.nextSibling;
            }
        return textValue;""",
        element, textPosition).strip()
```

How to call this in your case:

```
# print input
print(get_text_from_parent_by_postion(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("pre"),1))
#print output
print(get_text_from_parent_by_postion(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("pre"),2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Obtains all the text in  @id="problem-statement"

```
str=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="problem-statement"]').text
print(str[str.find('Input'):str.find('Constraints')])
```

Comment: Can you tell me why my method is not working because when I am entering //pre it is printing input and output so If I am excluding b tag it should print Input and Output(excluding 'Input','Output')